# Can not insert accents in MySQL REPL

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to run a MySQL database in a Docker container using the official image. I can run everything OK but I have a problem with inserting accents.

The thing is that I can not insert accents on the MySQL REPL (or CLI or shell or... I am not sure how to call it; I mean where you see the `mysql>` prompt). Nonetheless I can exit to the main Linux shell (prompt `#`) and insert accents normally.

I know that [UTF8 is not reliable](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) in MySQL so I tried to set `utf8mb4`. The character settings I do is:

```
mysql> set names utf8mb4;
mysql> set character_set_database=utf8mb4;
mysql> set character_set_server=utf8mb4;
mysql> set character_set_system=utf8mb4;
```

You can see what I have:

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "can not insert accents"? Are you unable to switch the keyboard layout? Does MySQL scream in pain? Does it kill a kitten? Does the computer go up in flames?

Comment: Or (for the sarcasm-impaired), exactly what happens when you try to insert data with accented letters in it from the `MySQL>` prompt? An error, the letters show up with accents on screen, but are inserted without accents (or as something else altogether), the letters don't show up with accents on screen, and insert just as seen on screen, or something else?

Comment: Sounds like the "mysql commandline tool".  Are you using "Terminal" for talking to the "shell"?  If so, check the "character encoding" of Terminal: "Terminal > Set Character Encoding".  It should say "Unicode (UTF-8)"

Comment: @mustaccio and @RDFozz I'm a native Spanish speaker and my keyboard layout is Spanish - ISO on macOS. I type the accute accent symbol `´` and then some vowel (a, e, etc.). Normally, there should appear that letter with an accent---i.e. `á`---but instead the MySQL REPL do not write that letter. The same when I copy and paste some word with accents---for instance I copy `salchichón` and when I paste it I have `salchichn`. @RickJames I use the default Terminal in macOS and is set to UTF-8. I have no problems on the Linux shell inside the container (prompt `#`), but on the MySQL REPL.

Comment: I presume the Docker images has been built with minimal configuration, possibly without the national character support compiled and/or installed. See if [any of this helps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-configuration.html).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. The problem might be that I was setting `utf8mb4` just for a database, not for the `mysqld` daemon.

Anyway I put here what I made. I first created a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mysql:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.utf8

COPY conf.d/ /etc/mysql/conf.d/

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD pass
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE gastos
```

As you can see, I copy a *conf.d* directory I just made. Inside this directory there is a *character_set.cnf* file:

```
[mysqld]
character_set_server = utf8mb4
collation_server = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

[ENV LANG=C.UTF-8](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/131#issuecomment-248413835) seems to be the upstream fix which doesn't require the generation of `en_US.utf8`